# How do I refresh a panel after a mouseClicked?

Tags: java, swing

I have a game to code in java with Swing. The classes of the game work but I'm having troubles with the GUI class. The printing methods use an object Graphics as parameter but I don't know how to use this. Here is the portion of the code :

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            Piece piece = joueur.getPosition();
            int positionClick = numberPiece(e.getX(), width) + numberPiece(e.getY(), height) * 10;
            int positionJoueur = Scenario.pieces.get(piece) - 1;
            if (positionClick==positionJoueur-1)
                joueur.deplacer('O');
            else if (positionClick==positionJoueur+1)
                joueur.deplacer('E');
            else if (positionClick==positionJoueur-10)
                joueur.deplacer('N');
            else if (positionClick==positionJoueur+10)
                joueur.deplacer('S');
            panel.updateUI();
            repaint();

        }

        private int numberPiece(int coord, int size) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                int x = i * size;
                if (coord < x) {
                    return (i - 1);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: `repaint` is the normal way, please don't call `updateUI` unless you're changing the look and feel. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Here is the window : http://puu.sh/mNFOT.png
Clicking shoud change the position of the sprite, calling joueur.deplacer() which has consequences for the paintComponent. I removed updateUI, and whenever I click nothing changes.

Comment: Go back and have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I really have no idea how I could crop the problematic part of the code... What should I do? It's kind of big, I thought the problem came from how I use the MouseListener, if you don't see any obvious mistake in this part then it could be anywhere, but I can't dump the whole thing.

Comment: That's why it's so important that you strive to create code that is cohesive and with low coupling, and that each of your classes is independently testable. If you create your code in this way, then it is often trivial to create your [mcve] if needed.

Comment: I think the problem is me, not the code. It was given as an exercise to fill, everything was done except the GUI class. What can I do ? I just don't understand how it works... http://pastebin.com/3VkHTb7D

Comment: If this method is reimplemented, super.paint(g) should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered

Comment: The purpose of Swing's RepaintManager class is to maximize the efficiency of repaint processing on a Swing containment hierarchy, and also to implement Swing's 'revalidation' mechanism

Comment: *"I really have no idea how I could crop the problematic part of the code..."* 'Lack of an MCVE' is a valid reason to close a question. I have already added one vote (out of 5 needed) towards that end. If you cannot figure out how to make an MCVE, SO is not the place to come asking for help.